# lrtest(likelihood ratio test) for count data using plgm package

Tags: r

See the two lines of code below. Can I use `lrtest` to check which is better? If not, why not and what should I do to choose a better one? Thank you in advance

```
law <- pglm(patents ~ lag(log(rd), 0:5) + scisect + log(capital72) + factor(year), PatentsRDUS,
            family = negbin, model = "within", print.level = 3, method = "nr",
            index = c('cusip', 'year'))

lap <- pglm(patents ~ lag(log(rd), 0:5) + scisect + log(capital72) + factor(year), PatentsRDUS,
            family = poisson, model = "pooling", index = c("cusip", "year"),
            print.level = 0, method="nr")
```

Comment: According to the documentation of the `pglm` package, the returned object contains the log-likelihood in the list element `logLik`. Consequently, it should be easy to perform a likelihood-ratio test by hand. I'm guessing you are referring to `lmtest::lrtest()` here, though. I'm not sure if that will work, but we cannot test it as you have not provided any sample data. The function has a default method that may work on `pglm` class objects. You are much more likely to get help here at SO if you provide sample data and reference the packages you use in your question.

Comment: thank you for your answer. just enter " > data("PatentsRDUS", package="pglm")" then you can get the data.